# Laravel Migration not working on Mac OS X with MySQL 8.0.11

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm running

> php artisan migrate:install

on MacOS X 10.13.6 with MySQL 8.0.11 and Laravel 5.5 and I'm getting the following:

> In PDOConnection.php line 50:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 46:
>                                                           SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 46:
>                                                                                     PDO::__construct(): Unexpected server respose while doing caching_sha2
>   auth     : 21

This is my .env section for the DB:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=store
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=abcd1234
```

I have access to MySQL through the terminal using those credentials (root as username and abcd1234 as password). Not quite sure what's failing.

Thanks.

Comment: This is to do with MySQL 8.0's authentication configuration. It's not Laravel specific. Focus on the `caching_sha2` part. You may find that MySQL 5.7 is fine.

Comment: You were right, thanks a lot!

Comment: I've seen this sort of thing pop up a lot lately as MySQL 8.0 made breaking changes, but I don't know of a solution off the top. If you do, posting a self-answer could help others.